# How can I check if three consecutive points are above the mean in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to check in R if three consecutive observations are above the mean, and if so, color them red? Any idea how can this be simply done?
For example:

```
set.seed(11)
x <- data.frame(meaure1 = rnorm(10,5,2))

mean1 <- mean(x$meaure1)

p <- ggplot(x, aes(x = meaure1, y = c(1:length(meaure1))))+ 
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line() +
  ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept =   mean(x$meaure1), color = 'black')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the base R function `rle`:

```
#create vector of run lengths
runs<-rle(ifelse(x$meaure1>mean(x$meaure1), 1, 0))
#find runs lenghts >= 3 and color red
runs$values<-ifelse(runs$lengths >=3, "red", "black")
#create the color vector
x$colors <- inverse.rle(runs)

ggplot(x, aes(x = 1:length(meaure1), y = meaure1))+ 
   geom_point(size = 2, colour=x$colors) +
   geom_line() +
   ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept =   mean(x$meaure1), color = 'black')
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping column where the group index is incremented only when the current row is not equal to the previous row element.  In this case, the `i1` is a logical column, and `rleid` on that column creates a numeric index.  Based on the index, create a new column of 'Color' by checking `if` `all` values in 'i1' are `TRUE` and (`&&`) if the number of rows are greater than or equal to 3 (`n() >= 3`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
x1 <-  x %>% 
   mutate(i1 = meaure1 > mean1) %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(i1)) %>% 
   mutate(Color =  if(n() >= 3 && all(i1)) "red" else "black") %>%
   ungroup
```

Then, plot with `ggplot`

```
 x1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number(), Mean = mean1) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = meaure1, color = Color, group = 1))  +
    geom_point(size = 2) + 
    geom_line() + 
    ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept =  mean1, color = 'black') +
    scale_colour_manual(values =c("black", "red")) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position='none')
```